# Maven - How to get list of dependencies excluding optional

Tags: java, maven

I want to get the list of dependencies for an artifact, including transitive dependencies but excluding (or at least flagging) [optional dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

The output of `mvn dependency:list` or `mvn dependency:tree` includes optional dependencies without any way to filter them out.

Comment: Interesting question(+1). But that I am wondering what is the use case for that?

Comment: Good question, I'm trying to migrate a set of project from Maven to Bazel. I ran into some issues because I was including optional dependencies that (log4j) that ended up causing trouble, so I would like to exclude them somehow.

Comment: Does `dependency:list` really include the transitive optional dependencies?

Comment: I checked with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), neither `dependency:list` nor `dependency:tree` shows optional transitive dependencies. Maybe I've missed something (I've used `maven-dependency-plugin` 2.8), but to be sure, could you provide an example (including Maven version, plugin versions, ...) where these commands include optional transitive dependencies?